# Changing the video playing on Youtube Embedded Player

Tags: video, hyperlink, youtube, embed

I know this is a repeated question. I basically need to make the youtube videos play on an embedded Youtube player on the site when clicking on the hyperlinks(containing links to Youtube videos). I found some answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/690018/524811 but I couldn't get it to work as I'm very new to Javascript. Hope you can assist. Here's my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Sample Page </title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready( function(){
        $(".button").click(function() {
        console.log($(this).find("a").attr("href"));
        $("#MOVIE").html(play($(this).find("a").attr("href"))); 
        return false; 
        });
    });
</script>

<object width="420" height="315"><param name="MOVIE" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/HsQIoPyfQzM?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/HsQIoPyfQzM?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
</br></br>
<li class="button"><a href="sPvqNMb4StI">Video 1</a></li>
<a href="http://youtu.be/sPvqNMb4StI"> THIS IS FIRST Video Link </a></br></br>
<a href="http://youtu.be/w7_Ccu21QVs"> THIS IS SECOND Video Link </a>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "I know this is a repeated question." - Really? then why ask again?

Comment: "I couldn't get it to work as I'm very new to Javascript. Hope you can assist." Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need `<li class="button">...</li>` wrapped around every one of the links. You only have it around the first one.

If you're copying code from that other question you reference, you need a `<div>` tag with the id `playvideo` and for your JavaScript code to reference it instead of `MOVIE`.

You didn't copy & paste the JavaScript `play() { ... }` [function from that other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/689463/2291). So when you try to call that method in your code it doesn't know what to do.